# Call Webapi route attribute from another project using ajax in script

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created a mvc application. Its contain script file as below,

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("hi");
       }
```

And i have created a webapi project with route attribute as below,

```
public class CaseController : ApiController
    {
        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod")]
        public List<CaseValues> AjaxCaseListMethod()
        {
            CaseModel users = new CaseModel();
            string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            List<CaseValues> caseList = new List<CaseValues>();
            caseList = users.GetCaseDetails(userName);
            // caseList = caseList.Take(10).ToList();
            return caseList;
        }
}
```

But my ajax call not hit the above webapi action. Its working when paste location directly in browser as below,

http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod

and also working within same project.

Please give you suggestion.

Comment: Where is the ajax application running from, this could be a CORS issue. Your API is running from localhost:55016, but your AJAX code is obviously running somewhere else.

Comment: And what HTTP status code for error are you getting? I trust it could be CORS error. Are you getting in the console No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access?

Comment: Hi just try by giving the url as follow ,

url: "/api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod",

And see it helps.hope it will, kindly let me know your feedback

Comment: see developer browser , see the error

Comment: Yes i have placed ajax in another solution. And Api in another solution.@Kyle

Comment: I have tried as your said but its not working.  I need to know how to call from ajax call in one solution to webapi route attribute in another solution. Please let me know if you have any other suggestion @KarthikElumalai

Comment: The error shows as "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:58389' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405." @AsifRaza

Comment: Hi its seems that calling the webapi from the another solution is not good. 

Kindly take a look at this:https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/258631

It will surely helpful for you.thanks

Comment: YOu need enable cross domain - usually cors use for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fixed my problem as per Asif Raza said. Yes i used CORS like below,

My ajax call from mvc project as done below,

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod",
            data: "",
            success: function (response) {
               alert("hi");
            }
});
```

Then we have to add below code in web.config file within web api project as below,

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

Then we have to write action as below,

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod")]
public List<CaseValues> AjaxCaseListMethod()
{
            CaseModel users = new CaseModel();
            string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            List<CaseValues> caseList = new List<CaseValues>();
            caseList = users.GetCaseDetails(userName);
            return caseList;
}
```

Now its working fine. Thanks..